# What is the jsrv.1 interface for?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-ex

I have a Juniper EX2200 switch running JunOS 10.4R4.5.

Under Configure -> System Properties -> Management Access, I can configure which interface allow management access.  There is a mystery interface call jsrv.1.

[image: EX2200 Screen Shot]

jsrv.1 is not listed in the configuration anywhere.  It does not show up on [this list of Juniper interface names](http://www.x83.net/juniper-interfaces-names).  I cannot find an explicit mention of what this interface is used for online, although I see it in other people's show interfaces output.

What is this interface and what is it used for?

**EDIT:**  We upgraded the EX2200 switches to JunOS 12.3R3.4 and the Jsrv.1 interface is gone now.  There is only "me" and "lo" now.

Comment: Everything I've found says it's used for an internal loopback,  but I can't find details.  Bottom line,  it's not something that you need to configure.

Comment: Do you have any sources you can share?

Comment: [This NOC project bug](http://bt.nocproject.org/browse/NOC-1167), which lists `jsrv` among all the other known internal interfaces on juniper switches

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interface `jsrv.1` is always associated to IP address `128.0.0.127`.

```
jsrv                    up    up
jsrv.1                  up    up   inet     128.0.0.127/2
```

An archive at [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=50CF09B9.8020403%40users.sourceforge.net&forum_name=nfdump-discuss) has the below command output snippet that shows a connection between `128.0.0.127` and port `6343` ([sFlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFlow) port)<sup>1</sup>:

```
tcpdump -v udp port 6343  -s 1500:
11:52:07.624977 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 254, id 5728, offset 0, flags [none],
 proto UDP (17), length 1484)
   10.1.1.1.60578 > collector.6343: sFlowv5, IPv4 agent 128.0.0.127,
 agent-id 17, seqnum 38496, uptime 1963373233, samples 8, length 1456
    flow sample (1), length 196,
<...snipped...>
```

There is a [Juniper Knowledge Center](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB15490) ([cached google link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:2wc5g1xRijgJ%3akb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index%3Fpage%3Dcontent%26id%3DKB15490+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk)) article that indicates there are 2 separate programs supporting the sFlow function, an agent and a collector.

> The sFlow monitoring system consists of an sFlow agent embedded in the
>   EX Switch and has a centralized collector. The sFlow agent’s two main
>   activities are random sampling and statistics gathering. It combines
>   interface counters and flow samples and sends them across the network
>   to the sFlow collector.  The sFlow collector uses the sFlow agent’s IP
>   address to determine the source of the sFlow data. This KB article
>   explains how the EX Switch assigns the IP address to the sFlow agent.

The `jsrv` interface appears to be a built-in Juniper sFlow sub-system that allows communication between the internal collector and agent.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Note, this is the **only** connection to 128.0.0.127 I've been able to locate.</sub>

Comment: Could you add details that show how you concluded there is a relationship between `jsrv` and sFlow? That would be worth an upvote :-)

Comment: @MikePennington The only real thing I have to go on is that tcpdump output, which is why I worded this with _"looks like"_. I can't imagine Juniper would publish documentation on how their internal sFlow components function behind the scenes. So unfortunately, I can't; the above is pretty much everything I've found about the `jsrv` interface and it's about as good as a shot in the dark.

Comment: ok, normally we discourage speculation in answers...

Comment: @MikePennington You're right, I didn't really connect that IP address to `jsrv`, I'll edit to add clarity.

Comment: I'm still surprised this is not officially documented anywhere.

Comment: @msemack I would imagine that was just an interface left open to JUNOS early on. Release `10.4R4.5` is several years old; it doesn't seem to be present anymore. I can confirm that this doesn't show up on any of mine.